# Is iOS capable of taking photo from camera while already recording audio?

Tags: ios, audio-recording, avaudiosession

Normally, while you are recording audio from the mic, opening camera takesover the audio session as expected. I am trying to find out if it is possible to NOT interrupt audio recording from the mic, while taking a photo / capturing single camera frame on demand?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.

But you may try below code and i think you can hear songs in head phones.

```
UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;

AudioSessionSetProperty ( 
    kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,                         
    sizeof (audioRouteOverride),                                      
    &audioRouteOverride                                               
);
```